# C# - Uninstall wpf application on click

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

i have created installer for my wpf application. After installing my application, it open one window of my application. now i want to give him option of uninstall this current application on that window.

is it possible in c#?

how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just start the Uninstaller from a button

```
Process.Start("uninstaller.exe");
```